# What is wrong with this code for an even-number fibonacci sequence in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop, fibonacci

```
def fibonacci(n):
    first = 0
    second = 1
    count = 0
    while count <= n:
        if (second % 2 == 0):
            first, second = second, first + second
            count += 1
    return first, second

print (fibonacci(4000000))
```

Can somebody please explain what is wrong with this code? In IDLE the page restarts but returns no answer. By the way, I'm a beginner programmer, only just finished the CodeAcademy course.

Comment: As a side-note, in Python you use `return first, second` to return 2 values.

Comment: Tip: put `print(first, second)` inside the `while` loop and observe what happens to the values.

Comment: What does "even-number Fibonacci sequence" mean? Is it a list of all even Fibonacci numbers up to the given element?

Comment: Also, it looks like this might be [Problem 2 from Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2). If it is, your algorithm and understanding of the problem are incorrect.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes it is! Please could you explain how so?

Comment: write out a few terms from the fibonacci sequence. Do you see a pattern? It's always odd, odd, even, odd, odd, even, isn't it?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Yeah I see the pattern now, but I'm assuming there's a alternate method, seems too much like a logical shortcut. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's project euler. You're supposed to take as many logical shortcuts as you can :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is for [Problem 2 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2), you're computing the wrong values. It asks for the sum of all even Fibonacci numbers up to a *value* of four million, not the four millionth value. That would be too large.

Since we want to keep generating values, we'll use a generator and combine it with [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile). Then we'll [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) it down to the even values, and find the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

```
import itertools

def fibonacci_gen():
    first = 0
    second = 1
    while 1:
        first, second = second, first + second
        yield second
```

```
>>> a = fibonacci_gen()
>>> sum(filter(lambda y: not y%2, itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x<=4e6, a)))
4613732
```

For a solution that doesn't use these features:

```
def fibonacci_4m():
    result = 0
    first = 0
    second = 1
    while second <= 4e6:
        first, second = second, first + second
        if not second%2:
            result += second
    return result
```

```
>>> fibonacci_4m()
4613732
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you're right it is, however I only just completed the CodeAcademy course, so I'm not familiar with 'yield', 'itertools.takewhile', filter( ) and a few of the other syntax as of yet. Could you simplify the syntax please?

Comment: I highly recommend learning about them instead. You can find out about `yield` from [the relevant question in the "Related" sidebar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python?rq=1), and `itertools.takewhile` and `filter` from the links embedded in my answer.

Comment: Having a tough time understanding the explanations on Stack Overflow, have you got any other simpler/ detailed explanations, you could refer me to?

Comment: @Kor13, I've added an alternate version that uses more basic operations.

Answer (score 0):

`second % 2` starts off as 1, which is not odd. Consequently your `while` loop doesn't run anything in the body, so the loop runs forever.

You probably want to always compute the next Fibonacci number, but only increment the count if the `second` is even.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have your count variable inside the if statement. You have created an infinite while loop. Move it outside of the if statement:

```
    if(second % 2 == 0):
        first, second = second, first + second
    count +=1
```

Also you will have to add more code to make this work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, nothing changes when the if statement fails to execute its conditional code. Try the following instead:

```
def main():
    for index in range(1, 41):
        print('even_fibonacci({}) = {}'.format(index, even_fibonacci(index)))

def even_fibonacci(index):
    for number in all_fibonacci():
        if not number & 1:
            index -= 1
            if not index:
                return number

def all_fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```